# React displays blank page after app build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

After running the command npm run build I got the build files without any error but once when I try to run the app it's showing blank page and error as [image]

I am unable to find where the issue is my index.html file is like

```
`<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="dashboard, admin, template, templates, sigma, bootstrap 4, react 4 templates, react 4 themes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- icons -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.png">

  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/icons/manifest.json">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
  <!-- <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/icons/ms-icon-144x144.png"> -->
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata:400,700|Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/weather-icons/2.0.9/css/weather-icons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/weather-icons/2.0.9/css/weather-icons-wind.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&libraries=places"></script>
</body>

</html>`
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "sigma",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "approve": "0.0.12",
    "approvejs": "^3.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "d3": "^5.5.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "froala-editor": "^2.9.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "harmony-reflect": "^1.6.0",
    "i18n": "^0.8.3",
    "ionicons": "^4.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "mgr-pdf-viewer-react": "^1.0.1",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "mustache": "^2.3.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "rc-slider": "^8.3.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-chartist": "^0.13.0",
    "react-datamaps": "^0.4.1",
    "react-datetime": "^2.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-easy-chart": "^1.0.0",
    "react-faux-dom": "^4.2.0",
    "react-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.9.1-1",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-intl-tel-input": "^5.0.5",
    "react-loadable": "^5.4.0",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.2.0",
    "react-rating": "^1.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-scripts": "^1.0.11",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "react-spinners": "^0.3.2",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.3.1",
    "reactable": "^0.14.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.0.1",
    "reapop": "^1.1.2",
    "recharts": "^1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "recompose": "^0.27.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
    "source-map": "^0.7.3",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "modules": false
        }
      ],
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer build/static/js/main.*",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src/scss --include-path ./node_modules src/scss -o src/css",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src/scss --include-path ./node_modules src/scss -o src/css --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build"
  }
}
```

I am confused with the occurrence of the error still it not mentioned where the error is 
While searching i came to know this error occurs due to missing of any scripts but can't figure out what am i doing wrong 
[image]

Comment: your react and react-dom versions must be the same in your package.json

Comment: tried but Still I am getting same error

Comment: have you tried to run your `analyze` script, the one that examines your main.js, does that work? Have you examine the content in your main.js and identify what wrong content there might be in that file?

Comment: no i am not aware of that how to do so ?

Comment: npm run analyze

Comment: kindly check the image ,I have edited

Comment: can't see any error in the image. I wanted to see whether main.js was corrupt. I am speculating the issue is within index.html inside the build folder, maybe cdn.polyfill.io is missing or similar. Are you sure that you have builded the solution using the same react and react-dom version?

Comment: You can review the official documentation to perform the application deployment https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

figured out the issue ! it is in the backend nodejs it didn't trigger the react's **index.html** file correctly

Answer (score 0):

You have upgraded react and react-dom packages but haven't update react-scripts package which is not compatible with react 16.
So you need to upgrade react-script package.

After that you can build it again and check, i am pretty sure that it work for you.